# Registration validation - if statement inside db.query doesn't work

Tags: node.js, postgresql, forms, express, crud

Everything works fine in my web application, just one thing.

When I try to `POST` form is a problem.

This is the RELEVANT code:

```js
app.post('/register' , (req,res)=>{
    const {body} = req,
    {email, passwrod , fullname} = body;

    db.query(`SELECT email FROM users` , (err,dbRes)=>{
        let arrEmail = dbRes.rows; //array of objects , every object contain row end result of query
        for(let i = 0; i<arrEmail.length; i++)
        {
            /*
            console.log(arrEmail[i].email); //email adress (output)
            console.log(email); //email from FORM (output)
            console.log(typeof(arrEmail[i].email)); //string (output)
            console.log(typeof(arrEmail[i].email)); //string (output)
             */
            if(email == arrEmail[i].email)
            {
                console.log("Same");
                break;
            }
        }

        res.send("dsds");
    });
});
```

No matter how much I tried to "play" and manipulate the if statement, with a `break` , without `break`, with `===` instead of `==`, with anything `---> if` statement always `false` even the values are the same.

When I tried, for example, `req.body()` with the annual string it actually matches, for example:

```
//this is actually work
    if(email == "adad@asdasd.com")
    {
        console.log("Same");
        break;
    }
```

1. **I know it's not the correct way**, but I just want to do this, for now, *in this way*
2. **I know also I need hash passwords**, doesn't matter, for the moment, please ignore.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need check if you have the email registered in your `users` table? If yes, it's better to put an `where email=${email}` and check if your select returned any row. If yes, it means that you have the same email registered in your `users` table.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Thanks for the idea :) It worked well